# 500 internal server error in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, internal

I have created an application using ASP.Net 3.5. But when I uploaded it to my server I get a "500 internal server error" message.

Comment: this link might be helpful: http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart

Comment: Based on quality of your question I give you same quality answer : Your server has an internal error, that the reason.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net will display a 500 if you don't have the custom errors property set to anything or it is set to `On`.

Add this to the web.config to see what the actual error is :

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Once you know what the actual error is, you can proceed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very generic error.

Start with the IIS logs and Event Logs.